# can i import a Hebrew library in java

Tags: java, libraries

Hello guys i am trying to make an encoder that takes a String and turns it into Hebrew characters, is there any way that i can import a Hebrew library in java?

i have tried to find something about this, but i haven't been able to find anything, can y'all help.

import java.?.?;

```
    import java.lang.*;
    import java.math.*;
```

> import libraries`import java.util.?;`

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if such a library/API exists. But you can easily create a "translator" by yourself using the [UNICODE for hebrew characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_and_HTML_for_the_Hebrew_alphabet). As described in [this book](https://books.google.fr/books?id=djuMgaEuBhQC&lpg=PA290&ots=kKm-blG5by&dq=Java%20Hebrew%20characters&hl=fr&pg=PA294#v=onepage&q&f=false), it should look like :

```
public char translate(char ch) {
    switch(ch) {
        case 'a' :
            return '\U05D0';
       //etc...
    }
}
```

Maybe there is such a API cause Hebrew is in the [supported encodings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html) in Java.

Comment: i actually figured it out, i just needed to enable UTF-8 in eclipse